# How do I modify my JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/7pwh9p8g/)

On click of "+" button bordered form elements are cloned and dynamically appended.

"Save Rules" button generates the JSON object of form field labels and values.
This is the JSON object being created on click of "Save Rules" button.

```
{
        "nameRules": "",
        "typeRules": "Type1",
        "descriptionRules": "XYZ\n                    ",
        "elhs": "",
        "op": "<=",
        "erhs": "",
        "datatype": "",
        "joinop0": "",
        "elhs0": "",
        "op0": "",
        "erhs0": "",
        "datatype0": ""
    }
```

How do I make it create the JSON object in the following format?

```
{
    "nameRules": "",
    "typeRules": "Type1",
    "descriptionRules": "XYZ\n                    ",
    "expressions": [{
                 "elhs": "",
                 "op": "<=",
                 "erhs": "",
                 "datatype": ""
                  },
                 {
                 "joinop0": "",
                 "elhs0": "",
                 "op0": "",
                 "erhs0": "",
                 "datatype0": ""
                 }]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: you can use Json.Parse

Comment: As @NayasSubramanian has said, use `JSON.parse(myJSON)` and then use normal javascript to edit the objects, and once you have finished, convert the object back to JSON using `JSON.stringify(myEditedObject)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Could you please create a fiddle to help me understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, code might not be pretty as I'm not expert in jquery, but it should work as expected: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9p7rewo5/)

```
  $('button.btn:contains("Save Rules")').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('hhh', $('form.form-horizontal#rules').find(':input:not(button):not(#joinop)').get());
    var jsonData = $('form.form-horizontal#rules')
      .find(':input:not(button):not(#joinop)').get()
      .reduce(function(acc, ele) {
        acc.expressions = acc.expressions||[];
        if (ele.closest( "#container" ) || ele.closest('.parent-border')) {
          if (ele.closest('.parent-border')) var i = 0;
          else var i = $( "#container .child-border" ).index( ele.closest( ".child-border" )) +1
          acc.expressions[i] = acc.expressions[i]||{};
          acc.expressions[i][ele.name || ele.id] = ele.value;
        }
        else acc[ele.name || ele.id] = ele.value;
        return acc;
      }, {});
    console.log(jsonData);
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4));
  });
```

Comment: Wow! This works like magic. How could you make the expressions array display after nameRules, typeRules, descriptionRules?

Comment: Just put expressions values into variable & append it to object after other operations - like that: [EDITED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kd5fjgnd/)

Comment: You made my day. Thanks so much! :D

Comment: How to concatenate the values within expressions array? I want to generate an equation reading the values of elhs,op,erhs,joinOp#,elhs#,op#,erhs#

Comment: It depends on speciffic needs. but I'd rather do this after jquery loop, with forEach or someting like that